threading/multiprocessing in python: how to run processes and main loop in parallel
I am trying to speed up a code using multiprocessing/threading. The problem involves producing some items (which can be done in parallel) and processing these items.
My first try was to use multiprocessing, but since I use ipython/jupyter (on MacOS) I used multiprocess. My code roughly looks as follows
from multiprocess import Queue, Process

def seek(q: Queue, a, b):
    while True:
        # seek for an item
        q.put(item)

def main_function(a, b, c)
    jobs = 3
    q = Queue()
    seek_jobs = [
        Process(target=dlp_ic_findrelation, args=(a, b))
        for _ in range(jobs)
    ]
    for p in seek_jobs:
        p.start()
    # init state
    while True:
        try:
            item = q.get()
            # process the item
            # update state
            if enough_items:
                for p in seek_jobs:
                    p.terminate()
                return result
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

Now in principle that works, however, by adding some print statements before the put/get commands I noticed that while the seek jobs run in parallel, the main program and the seek jobs don't. So I basically loose a potential speedup of a factor of 2. Since I figured, that this could be an iphyton/jupyter limitation, I also tried to execute the code from a file via the command line, but then the program runs by a factor of almost 10 slower (just the runtime for the main_function)!? If I replace multiprocess by multiprocessing it gets even slower by another 15%. Also the print statements from the seek jobs don't make it to stdout anymore, so I can't tell if things are done in parallel.
Of course I can pack the main while loop into another Process(), but this seems to create unnecessary overhead.
Next I tried to use threading, but then nothing runs in parallel and I get no speedup at all.
I would be particularly interested in this, because then I could easily move some of the processing to the seek jobs, which requires (read) access to data structures from the main processing loop.
Any hints on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Sounds like the perfect opportunity to learn about asyncio or threading, multiprocess is just a nightmare in Python, unnecessary here

There are definitely a lot of pitfalls in multiprocessing with python. My general order of operations for speeding up code is as follows: 1. make sure everything runs in numpy functions or similar (don't let native python do math). 2. make sure you're using an efficient algorithm, and caching everything you can within memory limitations (reduce disk IO). 3. Jit compile using numba. 4. multiprocessing. Depending on your application the first three can give many orders of magnitude speedup. Multiprocessing is much more limited unless you have a cluster (which is much harder to use anyway)

The absolute best thing to do is make sure you're profiling your code. It can be unintuitive where the actual slow parts are. 10x slower on terminal sounds like something is going wrong. Both terminal and jupyter are both the same CPython executable. They should be very comparable.

@Aaron This is just an implementation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm for fun. numpy does not seem to work well with big integers. And it seems my terminal uses a different (non silicon) version of python.
